# Source Tree GIT push failed with error 'The remote end hung up unexpectedly'

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am not able to check in source code from `GIT` I am using source tree client for `GIT`.

I am getting below error while pushing the code.

```
POST git-receive-pack (1141901 bytes)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: RPC failed; HTTP 413 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 413 Request Entity Too Large
Pushing to https://me@domain/branch.git
To https://me@domain/branch.git
 = [up to date]      3.4.0 -> 3.4.0
 = [up to date]      3.5.0 -> 3.5.0
Everything up-to-date
Completed with errors, see above.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when you try to push large files from git over HTTP(s).
The solution to this problem is to use ssh URL.

You need to create private and public keys(you can use pageant tool). The public key should be added under your bitbucket profile.
Then try `git push` it will solve the problem.